# How do you get Kanai's Cube?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just loaded up the new patch and there doesn't seem to be much direction on how to actually acquire this key new item. Zultan Kulle talked about it briefly, and then I had no quests indicating where to go next.

How exactly do I acquire Kanai's Cube?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just teleport to the new zone, Sescheron Ruins (act III, Top Right corner of map) and explore. I found it in the Elder Sanctum map area.

Comment: Confirmed. Elder Sanctum is a sub-level of Sesheron Ruins. You don't need to clear Sesheron Ruins to be able to enter the Elder Sanctum level.

Comment: I think its important to note that the Elder Sanctum is a sub-level of the Sescheron Ruins. When I originally read this answer I thought the Elder Sanctum was a *part* of Sescheron Ruins and I wasted a fair amount of time walking around before I noticed the name of one of the exits was "Elder Sanctum". So, you need to go to Sescheron Ruins and look for an exit labeled "Elder Sanctum" and the Cube will be in that area somewhere.

Comment: Also I might add. It's not a drop. It sits on a table in the Tomb of King Kanai's section which on my map was located on the right hand side. Literally the last part of "Ruins of Sescheron" I explored...

Answer (score 10):

Along with Kanai's Cube, [patch 2.3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19859662/patch-230-now-live-8-25-2015#patchfeatures) [also added](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19823807/patch-230-preview-ruins-of-sescheron-7-21-2015) the dungeon "[Ruins of Sescheron](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Ruins_of_Sescheron)". This dungeon appears around the [Arreat Crater](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Arreat_Crater), in Act 3. You must be playing Adventure Mode.

If you clear the dungeon, you will gain access to the [Tomb of King Kanai](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Tomb_of_King_Kanai), where you will find [Kanai's Cube](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Kanai's_Cube).